# Formatting an entire pandas dataframe as a string, row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which I'd like to print out with a special format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 3], 'B': [90, 74, 180], 'C': ["aabb","bbcc", "ccdd"]})
```

The required output is:

```
For x1, referenced by aabb, the address is 0x5a
For x5, referenced by bbcc, the address is 0x4a
For x3, referenced by aabb, the address is 0xb4
```

i.e. something like -

```
print('For x%i, referenced by %s, the address is %x' % (df.A, df.C, df.B)`
```

Concatenating the columns as strings does not work -

```
print('For' + df.A + df.C + df.B)
```

I can easily do it using `iterrows`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `apply` along `axis=1` using `format` with an appropriate format string.  Make sure to use dictionary unpacking within a lambda to get it done.

```
sfmt = 'For x{A}, referenced by {C}, the address is {B:#04x}'.format

df.apply(lambda x: sfmt(**x), 1)

0    For x1, referenced by aabb, the address is 0x5a
1    For x5, referenced by bbcc, the address is 0x4a
2    For x3, referenced by ccdd, the address is 0xb4
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I can't insert '\t' into sfmt to be printed as tabs? (They are printed as '\t' instead of tabs)